# Unity Pong AI movement speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, pong

I was trying to do AI for a Pong game in Unity C#, but the problem is AI seems to move with the same speed as the ball is flying. I cant seem to figure out how to make the AI move with a set speed or the same speed as player.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AIController : MonoBehaviour {

Transform Ball;
Transform Ai;

void Update () 
{
    //
    Ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Ball").transform;
    Ai = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Ai").transform;

    if (Ball.position.y > 0) {
        Debug.Log ("Ball Pos " + Ball.position.y);
        Ai.position = new Vector3(Ai.position.x, Ball.position.y, 0);
    }
    else if (Ball.position.y < 0) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Ball Pos " + Ball.position.y);
        Ai.position = new Vector3(Ai.position.x, Ball.position.y, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: At what point do you make it react to the player's behaviour?

Comment: It reacts to the movement of the ball, but for some reason with the same speed as the ball.

Comment: What do you *expect* your current code to do, other than AI y position tracking ball y position exactly?

Answer (score 3):

It is not that the AI is moving at the same speed at the ball, it's that the AI *has* the same position as the ball. Look at this:

```
Ai.position = new Vector3(Ai.position.x, Ball.position.y, 0);
```

The `AI.position.y` is always the position of the ball, `Ball.position.y`. This AI never loses.

You have to update the AI in a similar way you are probably updating the player. Make incrments or decrements in the AI.y. Just compare the position of the Ball and the position of the AI and update the last.

Something among the lines:

```
if (Ball.position.y > Ai.position.y)
{
    Ai.position.y += AiSpeed;
}
else
{
    Ai.position.y -= AiSpeed;
}
```